# Problem with xvideoservice thief

Tags: video, audio, cpu, conversion, flv

Xvideo service thief is an application that allows you to download and convert youtube videos into .avi format. 
The problem is when it tries to convert the .flv into a .avi. The audio in the video is not being played when you try to play the video. But the .flv works fine.
I have also enabled Intel(R) speedstep feature in my processor(Pentium Dual core E5200) to decrease the power consumed by the processor with the help of Granola software.
What might be the reason for the audio less video converter by xvideo service thief?
Could it be the enabling of intel(R) speedstep? 
Because the software works fine when its not enabled.
Is this possible?That the output some applications can be altered when enabling this processor feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel speedstep is a technology for slowing down the processor when not in use. For example, my proccessor usually runs at 3.8GHz, but if it's idle, the system will clock it down to 3.6, 3.2, 2.8, or even 2.0GHz based on how much processor time is needed by applications. With that said, this *shouldn't* affect video encoding or any other application in any manner, though that's impossible to know for sure.